# virtaul host not work when i unplugged nic and turn off wifi

Tags: networking

I am facing a strange problem with ubuntu 14.04. Previously i used ubuntu 12.04 and same thing worked.

I installed ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit) on my machine and installed LAMP(Apache2, Mysql and PHP) Virtual hosts on this machine. Virtual hosts work when internet connection is available but once i unplugged the cable and wifi connection. Vhost stop work.

Here is the config file of i am using

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.1.4:80>

      ServerName development.local
      ServerAlias www.development.local
      ServerAdmin nitinsonitest@gmail.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/development

    <Directory /var/www/development>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also add this in my hosts file (located at **/ets/hosts**)

**127.0.1.4 development.local**

One of my friend face same issue in window machine that was resolved by urn on dns client service. Can any one have any idea about this.

Please excuse me for bad english. Any hint will be appretiate.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Apache is a web server and it requires at least one active network interface to be able to work. When you turned off / unplugged your networks, you basically caused the network interfaces to become unavailable. To fix this, you could configure a local "Loopback Adapter" connection that will work over your loopback IP (127.0.0.1) and will always be available.

Note however that if you configure multiple network adapters that may be on or off in different combinations, you will need to configure your VHosts for multiple IP addresses (you will have at least one IP address for each network adapter). Otherwise, you will find different sets of VHosts becoming unavailable when you turn off particular network connections.

Comment: Thanks Sujay. I am a developer so not too much good in network management. Can you please tell me how can i can configure Loopback Adapter

Comment: I am not a "hands on" Linux guy. But you can try this blog entry: http://linuxbhandari1.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-install-looback-interface-in.html

Comment: I sujay i just cheked the ifconfig and loopback is already working. When internet is not available the localhost is work. Also virtual host work if i define ip inconfig file but cant map to server name mean if i use 127.0.0.4 to browse it work but if i use development.local then it not work. 

i think it is some dns client related thing